# Coding FTP service over TCP in C code

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ftp

I'm trying to code a TCP FTP service for a multi-threaded server. I found this tutorial [http://www.mario-konrad.ch/wiki/doku.php?id=programming:multithreading:tutorial-04](http://www.mario-konrad.ch/wiki/doku.php?id=programming%3amultithreading%3atutorial-04) which is very helpful to understand the multithreading of clients for the TCP protocol. In fact, this code create a server that can accept multiple connections from different clients simultaneously.

However, I'm struggling to find how to apply the ftp service on it. Precisely how to put and get a file to and from the FTP server.

Any help please?

Comment: You need to read [RFC 959](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc0959), which defines the FTP protocol.  You have to implement the reading of FTP requests and sending of FTP responses on top of your TCP logic.

Comment: In addition to the RFC, I recommend looking at [this guide](http://cr.yp.to/ftp.html) that describes each common FTP transaction and how it's implemented by popular servers.

Answer (score 4):

The code below is an assignment I did for a networking paper last year. Hope it helps.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 800
#define WSVERS MAKEWORD(2,0)

WSADATA wsadata;    
void    wy_fileName_collector(char  *_buffer, char  *_nameBuffer);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    //INITIALIZATION
    struct sockaddr_in localaddr,remoteaddr;
    struct sockaddr_in remoteaddr_act;

    SOCKET s,ns;
    SOCKET s_data_act=0;

    char send_buffer[BUFFERSIZE],receive_buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    char fileName[40];


    int n,bytes,addrlen;
    memset(&localaddr,0,sizeof(localaddr));//clean up the structure
    memset(&localaddr,0,sizeof(remoteaddr));//clean up the structure

    //WSASTARTUP
    if (WSAStartup(WSVERS, &wsadata) != 0)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        printf("WSAStartup failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //SOCKET
    s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s <0)
    {
        printf("socket failed\n");
    }
    localaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if (argc == 2) localaddr.sin_port = htons((u_short)atoi(argv[1]));
    else localaddr.sin_port = htons(1234);//default listening port
    localaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;//server address should be local

    //BIND
    if (bind(s,(struct sockaddr *)(&localaddr),sizeof(localaddr)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Bind failed!\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    //LISTEN
    listen(s,5);

    while (1)
    {
        addrlen = sizeof(remoteaddr);

        //NEW SOCKET newsocket = accept
        ns = accept(s,(struct sockaddr *)(&remoteaddr),&addrlen);
        if (ns <0 ) break;
        printf("accepted a connection from client IP %s port %d \n",inet_ntoa(remoteaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(localaddr.sin_port));

        //Respond with welcome message
        sprintf(send_buffer,"\n==220 Welcome to Alan's FTP site== \r\n\n");
        bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);

        while (1)
        {
            n = 0;
            while (1)
            {
                //RECEIVE
                bytes = recv(ns, &receive_buffer[n], 1, 0);//receive byte by byte...

                //PROCESS REQUEST
                if ( bytes <= 0 ) break;
                if (receive_buffer[n] == '\n')
                { /*end on a LF*/
                    receive_buffer[n] = '\0';
                    break;
                }
                if (receive_buffer[n] != '\r') n++; /*ignore CRs*/
            }
            if ( bytes <= 0 ) break;

            printf("-->DEBUG: the message from client reads: '%s' \r\n", receive_buffer);

            /**
              * @brief  Exception handling
              */
            if(strncmp(receive_buffer,"USER",4)  && strncmp(receive_buffer,"PASS",4)    &&  strncmp(receive_buffer,"SYST",4)
                    &&strncmp(receive_buffer,"PORT",4)   && strncmp(receive_buffer,"STOR",4)    &&  strncmp(receive_buffer,"RETR",4)
                    &&strncmp(receive_buffer,"LIST",4)  &&  strncmp(receive_buffer,"NLST",4)    &&  strncmp(receive_buffer,"QUIT",4))
            {
                sprintf(send_buffer,"202 Command not implemented, superfluous at this site. \r\n");
                bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
            }


            if (strncmp(receive_buffer,"USER",4)==0)
            {
                printf("Logging in \n");
                sprintf(send_buffer,"331 Password required \r\n");
                bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                if (bytes < 0) break;
            }

            if (strncmp(receive_buffer,"PASS",4)==0)
            {
                printf("Typing password (anything will do... \n");
                sprintf(send_buffer,"230 Public login sucessful \r\n");
                bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                if (bytes < 0) break;
            }

            if (strncmp(receive_buffer,"SYST",4)==0)
            {
                system("ver > tmp.txt");

                FILE *fin=fopen("tmp.txt","r");//open tmp.txt file
                sprintf(send_buffer,"150 Transfering... \r\n");
                bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                char temp_buffer[80];
                while (!feof(fin))
                {
                    fgets(temp_buffer,78,fin);
                    sprintf(send_buffer,"%s",temp_buffer);
                    send(s_data_act, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                }
                fclose(fin);
                sprintf(send_buffer,"226 File transfer completed... \r\n");
                bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);

                if (bytes < 0) break;
            }

            //PORT
            if(strncmp(receive_buffer,"PORT",4)==0)
            {
                s_data_act = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                //local variables
                unsigned char act_port[2];
                int act_ip[4], port_dec;
                char ip_decimal[40];
                sscanf(receive_buffer, "PORT %d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",&act_ip[0],&act_ip[1],&act_ip[2],&act_ip[3],(int*)&act_port[0],(int*)&act_port[1]);
                remoteaddr_act.sin_family=AF_INET;//local_data_addr_act
                sprintf(ip_decimal, "%d.%d.%d.%d", act_ip[0], act_ip[1], act_ip[2],act_ip[3]);
                printf("IP is %s\n",ip_decimal);
                remoteaddr_act.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip_decimal);
                port_dec=act_port[0]*256+act_port[1];
                printf("port %d\n",port_dec);
                remoteaddr_act.sin_port=htons(port_dec);

                if (connect(s_data_act, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr_act, (int) sizeof(struct sockaddr)) != 0)
                {
                    printf("trying connection in %s %d\n",inet_ntoa(remoteaddr_act.sin_addr),ntohs(remoteaddr_act.sin_port));
                    sprintf(send_buffer, "425 Something is wrong, can't start the active connection... \r\n");
                    bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);

                    closesocket(s_data_act);
                }
                else
                {
                    sprintf(send_buffer, "200 Ok\r\n");
                    bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                    printf("Data connection to client created (active connection) \n");
                }
            }

            /**
              * @brief  STOR
              */
            if((strncmp(receive_buffer,"STOR",4)==0))
            {
                memset(&fileName, 0, strlen(fileName));
                wy_fileName_collector(receive_buffer,   fileName);

                if(fopen(fileName,"w")  ==  NULL)
                {
                    printf("@alan:line1\n");
                    sprintf(send_buffer,"450 Requested file action not taken. \r\n");
                    bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    FILE *fout=fopen(fileName,"w");

                    sprintf(send_buffer,"150 File status okay; about to open data connection. \r\n");
                    bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                    while(1)
                    {
                        n = 0;
                        while(1)
                        {
                            //RECEIVE
                            bytes = recv(s_data_act, &receive_buffer[n], 1, 0);//receive byte by byte...
                            //PROCESS REQUEST
                            if ( bytes <= 0 ) break;

                            if (receive_buffer[n] == '\n')
                            { /*end on a LF*/
                                receive_buffer[n] = '\0';
                                break;
                            }

                            if (receive_buffer[n] != '\r') n++; /*ignore CRs*/
                        }
                        if ( bytes <= 0 ) break;
                        fprintf(fout,"%s\n",receive_buffer);
                    }

                    sprintf(send_buffer,"226 File transfer completed... \r\n");
                    bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);

                    fclose(fout);
                    closesocket(s_data_act);
                }
            }

            /**
              * @brief  RETR
              */
            if((strncmp(receive_buffer,"RETR",4)==0))
            {
                memset(&fileName, 0, strlen(fileName));
                wy_fileName_collector(receive_buffer,   fileName);

                if(fopen(fileName,"r")==NULL)
                {
                    sprintf(send_buffer,"450 Requested file action not taken. \r\n");
                    bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    FILE *fin=fopen(fileName,"r");//open tmp.txt file
                    sprintf(send_buffer,"150 Transfering... \r\n");
                    bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                    char temp_buffer[80];
                    while (!feof(fin))
                    {
                        fgets(temp_buffer,78,fin);
                        sprintf(send_buffer,"%s",temp_buffer);
                        send(s_data_act, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                    }
                    fclose(fin);
                    sprintf(send_buffer,"226 File transfer completed... \r\n");
                    bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                }
                closesocket(s_data_act);
            }



            //LIST or NLST
            if ( (strncmp(receive_buffer,"LIST",4)==0) || (strncmp(receive_buffer,"NLST",4)==0))
            {
                system("dir > tmp.txt");

                FILE *fin=fopen("tmp.txt","r");//open tmp.txt file
                sprintf(send_buffer,"150 Transfering... \r\n");
                bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                char temp_buffer[80];
                while (!feof(fin))
                {
                    fgets(temp_buffer,78,fin);
                    sprintf(send_buffer,"%s",temp_buffer);
                    send(s_data_act, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                }
                fclose(fin);
                sprintf(send_buffer,"226 File transfer completed... \r\n");
                bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);

                closesocket(s_data_act);
            }


            //QUIT
            if (strncmp(receive_buffer,"QUIT",4)==0)
            {
                printf("Quit \n");
                sprintf(send_buffer,"221 Connection closed by the FTP client\r\n");
                bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                if (bytes < 0) break;
                closesocket(ns);
            }
        }
        //CLOSE SOCKET
        closesocket(ns);
        printf("disconnected from %s\n",inet_ntoa(remoteaddr.sin_addr));
    }
    closesocket(s);//it actually never gets to this point....use CTRL_C
}

/**
  * @brief  Return file name from the string passed in.
  */
void wy_fileName_collector(char *_buffer, char  *_nameBuffer)
{
    char bf[BUFFERSIZE];
    char sep[2] = " "; //separation is space
    char *word;
    int  wcount=0;

    strcpy(bf, _buffer);
    for (word = strtok(bf, sep);word;word = strtok(NULL, sep))
    {
        wcount++;
        if(wcount == 2) // jump the first space"_".
        {
            strcpy(_nameBuffer, word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it helps very much (`gcc ftp.c -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -o ftp.exe`). It works through windows `ftp` command, but Total Commander ftp client hangs on welcome message. Is there a way to make it work in totalcmd?

Comment: Already found out: remove  '==' from hello message before '220' so that the line is `sprintf(send_buffer,"\n220 Welcome to Alan's FTP site \r\n\n");`.

Answer (score 1):

FTP uses two TCP connections to transfer files: a control connection and a data connection.

[Establish a control connection](http://cr.yp.to/ftp/greeting.html) to the FTP server, and [log in](http://cr.yp.to/ftp/user.html).

Next, [establish the data connection](http://cr.yp.to/ftp/retr.html). If you are connecting from behind a router then send the `PASV` command to ask the server to listen on a new data socket and send the IP/port back to you. If you're not behind a router then you will need to listen on a new data socket and use the `PORT` command to send the IP/port to the server.

Once the data connection is established, [send the STOR (upload) or RETR (download) command over the control connection](http://cr.yp.to/ftp/stor.html) to begin the transfer.

Data going over the control socket would look something like this:

```
(Open Control Connection)
SERVER: 220 System Ready
CLIENT: USER MyUserName
SERVER: 331 Please specify the password.
CLIENT: PASS MyPassword
SERVER: 230 Login successful.
CLIENT: TYPE I
SERVER: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
CLIENT: PASV
SERVER: 227 Entering Passive Mode (173,254,254,254,211,37)
(Client connects data connection to the specified address)
CLIENT: RETR example.html
SERVER: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for example.html (10403 bytes).
SERVER: 226 File send OK.
(Both close the data connection)
CLIENT: QUIT
SERVER: 221 Goodbye
(Both close control connection)
```